# Information about A. Aubry

Tags: ho.history-overview

A. Aubry published a paper entitled "Les Logarithmes avant Neper" in the 1906 edition of L'Enseignement Mathématique signed simply "A. Aubry (Beaugency, Loiret)".  Does anyone know what the A. stood for (perhaps Auguste?) or anything more about this A. Aubry?

The only other reference I've found is that it may have been the same A. Aubry that wrote the forward to "Carrés Magiques au degré n" by Général Cazalas but this is pure conjecture.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Cheers, Scott

Comment: Forward=foreword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is Auguste Aubry. The *L'Enseignement Mathématique* volume is on archive.org, and there is an earlier paper in it on hyperbolic functions by Aubry. The material and location suggests a school teacher. There is more about him (I presume) in http://www.univ-lille1.fr/bustl-grisemine/pdf/extheses/50416-1999-Decaillot-Laulagnet.pdf which is about Edouard Lucas and his associates. On p. 74 of the PDF, Aubry is in a footnote about people who published minor research in the AFAS publications (AFAS is the Association Française pour l'Avancement des Sciences). On p. 96 there it is Auguste Aubry writing something about magic squares in an edition of Fermat. Aubry with A. Gérardin did translation work on some paper of Lucas. He also wrote a paper on factorisation methods (p. 207). More about the Lucas work in http://www.math.ens.fr/culturemath/histoire%20des%20maths/pdf/Decaillot_textile.pdf by the same author.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks much, Charles.  BTW, Aubry ends the paper I cited with the famous (in some circles) ...

The use of this book is quite large, my dear friend
No matter how modest it looks,
You study it carefully and find that it gives
As much as a thousand big books.